# using a prototype on potentially empty parameters in JS

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm updating a script that checks parameters like this:

`if (config.param) {//do...}`

This has lead to some issues in truthiness. I'd implemented a truthy() function as a prototype so as to be able to do the following:

`if (config.param.truthy()) {//do...}`

That seemed fine until I remembered that the config object only contains params being explicitly set. So config.value is usually undefined as opposed to false.

I'd added the prototype within an appropriate scope via `String/Number/Boolean.prototype.truthy`. 
Is it possible to implement the prototype on the config object such that it will be able to return false on non-defined parameters?

Edit: My question is not about the truthiness (I can simply use a function), but instead how to implement a prototype on an object such that it is inherited by its properties, which may be different types or non-existent.

Comment: "*I'd implemented a truthy() function as a prototype*" - that was a really bad idea. You should implement it as a static function to which you pass the value as an argument. And you really should not name it "truthy", as that implies the JS truthiness concept. What value do you really want to accept?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're trying to solve? Like, in particular, what are these "issues in truthiness"?

Comment: use object detection to make sure properties you want are defined, using `in` or `hasOwnProperty` or `typeof` or `x.y==null` (which hits `null` and `undefined`)  for values that can be falsy.

Comment: haha, maybe "truthish()". These are my false values: false, "false", 0, "0", "" (empty string), null, undefined, NaN. !== false =  true.

Answer (score 0):

`if ("param" in config && !!config.param) {//...`

Or if you want to use a default value if undefined then

`config.param = config.param || defaultValue`

The whole problem with prototyping in this case is that falsey values will not get autoboxed to `objects` and so attempting to call methods of them will result in error.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that your params will all be different types of data, then your approach of adding prototype methods for Strings/Booleans/etc could work well. Then you could simply see if that property exists by doing

```
if (config.hasOwnProperty("param") && config.param.truthy() ) {//do...}
```

or if you're using dynamic property names

```
if( config.hasOwnProperty(param) && config[param].truthy() ) {//do...}
```

Comment: This throws in cases such as `config = {param: null}`. Also, you'd need to pass the string `"param"` not the variable `param` to `hasOwnProperty`.

Comment: This is not true, `var obj = {foo: null}; obj.hasOwnProperty("foo");` will output `true`. You are correct on the string, I was assuming it was a dynamic property name. I've edited to cover both cases

Comment: The goal is also to keep the conditional concise, avoiding multiple cases to test. I've used `if (config.param !== false && config.param !== "false" && config.param !== 0) to catch a few instances where user input varies wildly, but am hoping to keep it cleaner

Comment: If you really want to keep it clean in this fashion, you could create a new Object.prototype.isTruthy() which would first check to see if the property exists (i.e. copy the source code for hasOwnProperty) and then check the type of the value and then use your logic from your already made .truthy methods.

Comment: @AJFunk: I meant that the `config.param.truthy()` throws when the property exists but is null or undefined.